# Accessing PHP class property generated by method

Tags: php

I feel like I'm missing something incredibly stupid here. I am not too familiar with OOP principals, specifically in PHP and am trying to learn. How do I access a class method's property in PHP? I specifically want to get the $AWSresponse property that is returned from this method. The value of $AWSresponse in JSON form is below.

In UploadHandler.php I have the post() method (full UploadHandler.php class is [here](https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/8172999)):

```
public $AWSresponse;
public function post($print_response = true) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
        return $this->delete($print_response);
    }
    $upload = isset($_FILES[$this->options['param_name']]) ?
        $_FILES[$this->options['param_name']] : null;
    // Parse the Content-Disposition header, if available:
    $file_name = $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION') ?
        rawurldecode(preg_replace(
            '/(^[^"]+")|("$)/',
            '',
            $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION')
        )) : null;
    // Parse the Content-Range header, which has the following form:
    // Content-Range: bytes 0-524287/2000000
    $content_range = $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE') ?
        preg_split('/[^0-9]+/', $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE')) : null;
    $size =  $content_range ? $content_range[3] : null;
    $files = array();
    if ($upload && is_array($upload['tmp_name'])) {
        // param_name is an array identifier like "files[]",
        // $_FILES is a multi-dimensional array:
        foreach ($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value) {
            $files[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                $upload['tmp_name'][$index],
                $file_name ? $file_name : $upload['name'][$index],
                $size ? $size : $upload['size'][$index],
                $upload['type'][$index],
                $upload['error'][$index],
                $index,
                $content_range
            );
        }
    } else {
        if( isset($_POST['fileSourceChooser']) && $_POST['fileSourceChooser']=='dropbox' ){

            //http://justinvincent.com/page/1087/how-to-get-the-mime-type-of-a-remote-file-in-php-with-redirects
            function get_url_mime_type($url){
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
                curl_exec($ch);
                return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
            }
                $upload=$_POST['files']; ////if just a regular post
                $upload['parse_url']=parse_url($upload['link']);
                $upload['url']='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com'.$upload['parse_url']['path'];
                    $files[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                        $upload['url'],
                        $file_name ? $file_name : $upload['name'],
                        $size ? $size : $upload['bytes'],
                        get_url_mime_type($upload['url']), 
                        "", 
                        null, null,
                        $content_range
                    );  

                    file_put_contents(
                        $this->options['upload_dir'].'thumbnail/'.$upload['name'],
                        fopen($upload['thumbnail'], 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND //$append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                    );                        
        }
        else{
            // param_name is a single object identifier like "file",
            // $_FILES is a one-dimensional array:
            $files[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                isset($upload['tmp_name']) ? $upload['tmp_name'] : null,
                $file_name ? $file_name : (isset($upload['name']) ?
                        $upload['name'] : null),
                $size ? $size : (isset($upload['size']) ?
                        $upload['size'] : $this->get_server_var('CONTENT_LENGTH')),
                isset($upload['type']) ?
                        $upload['type'] : $this->get_server_var('CONTENT_TYPE'),
                isset($upload['error']) ? $upload['error'] : null,
                null,
                $content_range
            );                
        }
    }
        $AWSresponse = $this->generate_response(
        array($this->options['param_name'] => $files),
        $print_response
    );
    return $AWSresponse;
}
```

In index.php I have:

```
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
$r = $upload_handler->AWSresponse;
var_dump($r); // returns NULL
```

This class (and associated jquery plugin) dumps the following to the browser's console from $AWSresponse, however:

```
{"files":[{"name":"Test(7).mov","size":1202952,"type":"video\/quicktime","url":"https:\/\/prefix.s3.amazonaws.com\/bucket\/Test%20%287%29.mov","deleteUrl":"https\/\/mysite.com\/server\/php\/?file=Test%20%287%29.mov&_method=DELETE","deleteType":"POST"}]}
```

Comment: vardump should be var_dump

Comment: Whoops. I've fixed the code, but am left with the same problem.

Comment: I don't really get what your issue is? What is the output _suppose_ to look like?

Comment: I'm trying to access the output via PHP. All the information makes it from the class to the jquery plugin, but I can't figure out how I can get my hands on it so I can insert into my database.

Comment: Just call your `post()` method to get `$AWSresponse` the first time around. After that, the variable is populated and you can access it directly. What I'm wondering, however, is why we have to explain your code to you? Did you not write that method?

Comment: Just a note: be _very_ careful when you're creating functions inside if statements. If you run this method twice, you might end up with "Cannot redeclare function get_url_mime_type". Add it as a protected class method instead.

Comment: I wish I could write a class this advanced domdom. It was provided by a contributor for the jquery-file-upload plugin.

Comment: If you look in the UploadHandler class, you'll see that there are only 4 public methods: head(), get(), post() and delete(). So all you can do with an object of this class is call one of those. You are referencing "$upload_handler->AWSresponse" which does not exist so you get null.

Comment: @Nikkorian, that makes sense. When I tried to do `$upload_handler->$post` I get an error that I `cannot access an empty property`, which deterred me from trying that. Is that pointing me down the right path?

Comment: You're mixing up _properties_ (`$class->$property`) with _methods_ (`$class->method()`). `post()` is a method, not a property, which is why `$class->$post` doesn't work.

Comment: And now I realize that it was a stupid mistake. Thank you @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this approach:

```
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
$myAWSresponse = $upload_handler->post();
var_dump($myAWSresponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `$this->AWSresponse` to access class property in `function post()` like:

```
return $this->AWSresponse;
```

and when you assign value in `$AWSresponse` use `$this->AWSresponse` like:

```
$this->AWSresponse = $this->generate_response(
        array($this->options['param_name'] => $files),
        $print_response
    );
```

Comment: Does $this work if I'm calling it from outside of the class?

Comment: No. `$this` refers to the instance of the "current" object.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Maybe I'm cart before wagoning this in my head. The class is doing what I want it to do and it's outputting data to the browser's console. Am I wrong in thinking I need to modify the class?